# How to clip from polygon for MODIS

Tags: clip, modis

I'm studying GEE for a project, and I want to clip from a polygon in MODIS. How to I do this?

I use the MODIS MOD10A1.006 Terra Snow Cover Daily Global 500m.
I also use filterbounds instead of clip, but its not working and shows me the whole extent.

```
Map.addLayer(geometry,{},'alaska')

// Create variables for 2000 summer period
var summer_2020 = ee.Filter.date('2020-06-01','2020-09-30');
var summer_2021 = ee.Filter.date('2021-06-01','2021-09-30');
var summer_2022 = ee.Filter.date('2022-06-01','2022-09-30');

// Create the intergrated date filter: 2000
var summerFilter_2020 = ee.Filter.or(summer_2020, summer_2021, summer_2022);
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD10A1")
                  .filter(summerFilter_2020)
                  
var image_MD_2020 = dataset.mean().clip(geometry);
var snowCover = dataset.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
var snowCoverVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 100.0,
  palette: ['black', '0dffff', '0524ff', 'ffffff'],
};
Map.setCenter(-41.13, 76.35, 2);
Map.addLayer(snowCover, snowCoverVis, 'Snow Cover');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot clip an image collection in GEE. You first need to reduce it to an image which you can then clip, so:

```
var snowCover = dataset.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
```

Should be, for example,

```
var snowCover = dataset.select('NDSI_Snow_Cover').mean().clip(geometry);
```